# Reasons for slow Simplex Performance

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, simplex

Could someone please list the main reasons why a linear are model is running slow and how to avoid them?

Speed improvement Tipps are also welcome.

I did some tests with a quite large linear model and ended up having different performances. One thing I realized was that if I have coefficients > 1 in the objective function it slows down the performance quite a lot.

I used lpsolve as simplex solver.

Comment: LpSolve is not always the fastest solver around. You may want to have a look at CBC (open source; often faster than LpSolve) or Cplex and Gurobi (commercial; typically much faster).

Comment: Thank you very much! I checked the solver and even the source files look way more intuitive...I think I could use it way better than lpsolve. I'll take a look at the performance later!